# PDOException - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'MyDataValue' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

First of all, I've seen this in numerous places on Stack Overflow, but I still can't get this error to go away. Some information about this particular issue is below:

The below code is the MySQL code which I used to create the table (where I want to insert the particular record):

```sql
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `energymeter`.`Node` (
  `node_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `node_name` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`node_id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `node_name_UNIQUE` (`node_name` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The below code is where it seems to be failing (resulting in the error given in the thread title):

```
$node_name_value = $line_of_text[2]; // In this example, the value would be 'MyDataValue'
$insert_demand_record = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Demand (date, time, trading_period, demand_value, Node_node_id) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%d %M %Y'), STR_TO_DATE('$time', '%k:%i:%s'), $trading_period, $demand_value, (SELECT Node.node_id FROM Node WHERE Node.node_name = $node_name_value))");
$insert_demand_record->execute();
```

EDIT: After further testing, changing the above code doesn't work, but if I alter the code below (with a change to the '$node_name_value value), I see the value changing in the browser (e.g. if I set $node_name_value to 'SomeRandomValue', the error would be something like 'Unknown column 'SomeRandomValue'...

```
//Ignoring items of same name that already exist (since there is a UNIQUE constraint
//on the 'node_name' column.
$insert_stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT IGNORE INTO Node(node_name) VALUES(:node_value)');

//Bind the node name with the query
$node_name_value = $line_of_text[2];
$insert_stmt->bindParam(':node_value', $node_name_value);

//Execute PDO insert statement
$insert_stmt->execute();
```

If anyone could help me out with this issue, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: There _is_ not even a WHERE clause in that query – so pretty sure you are looking at the wrong query …

Comment: @CBroe Oops sorry for that, have updated the post now... Am not sure if you can do inner SELECT statements using PDO...

Comment: You need to quote your values `WHERE Node.node_name = "$node_name_value"`, but really you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: I can't decipher your latest edit. does the below code work? What fo you change it to?

Answer (score -1):

The following code managed to make things work for me...

```
$insert_demand_record = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Demand (date, time, trading_period, demand_value, Node_node_id) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%d %M %Y'), STR_TO_DATE('$time', '%k:%i:%s'), $trading_period, $demand_value, (SELECT Node.node_id FROM Node WHERE Node.node_name = :node_name_value))");

$insert_demand_record->bindValue(':node_name_value', $node_name_value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert_demand_record->execute();
```

Thanks to the user 'Burhan Khalid' for suggesting the edit - will now be using prepared statements more...

Comment: You have been told to use prepared statements, not quotes.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Sorry for that, I updated my answer with what I should have put in the first place...

Comment: Sorry for being so strict, but you have to use placeholders for ALL the dynamical string and numeric literals, not only one.